# how to convert/revert icons from microsoft word into the original string in html and then passing it to php server

Tags: php, html

I'm using a textarea and TinyMCE plugin in my html page. I wanted to let users to paste things from microsoft word into the textarea and then they can submit the form and the content would be saved in a mysql table. when the user types `:)` in microsoft word it automatically becomes a smiley face, so when the user copy and pastes from microsoft word into the textarea, the smiley face is still there.

but now when the user submits the form, the smiley face turned into `????`. what workaround should I use so that I can insert the string `:)` to the table? the string field has Character set `utf8` and the Collation is `utf8_unicode_ci`.

I tried using `htmlspecialchars` on the variable before inserting it and I used `htmlspecialchars_decode` when displaying it on another html page, but it's still shown as `????`

here's a visual

`word document`

[image: word document]

`TinyMCE`

[image: tinymce]

`inserted data`

[image: inserted data]

Comment: _"what workaround should I use "_ - don't use any workarounds: **fix** your encoding gap problem properly by isolating the component that's not preserving UTF-8 encoding correctly.

Comment: @Dai and how exactly do I do that?